# CSS centering text in parent with variable height

Tags: html, css

[image: Look at the image below, it explains my question]

So basically I need to center (vertically) text, but the height is variable, since it can be on multiple lines, how can I do this?

What I've tried:

```
.box {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
}

.box {
  margin: 50% auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I don't know if this is even possible or if I have to correct it with JS.

Comment: This might help you http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:table-cell`

```
.box {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    height:200px;
    display:table-cell;
    width:450px
}
```

**[DEMO - Single line](http://jsfiddle.net/essts/3/)**

**[DEMO - Multi line](http://jsfiddle.net/essts/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, works vertically and horizontally.

HTML:

```
<div class="area">
      <div class="bubble">
          <p>To look best, text should really be centered inside this bubble both vertically and horizontally.</p>
      </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
   .area { 
      width: 300px; 
      height: 300px; 
      background: url(../images/abe-bg.png) no-repeat; 
      position: relative;
    }

    .bubble { 
      position: absolute; 
      left: 93px; 
      top: 21px; 
      width: 135px; 
      height: 84px; 
      display: table; 
    }

    .bubble p {
      display: table-cell; 
      vertical-align: middle; 
      text-align: center; 
    }​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gjExY/)